# How to validate code39 via regex?

Tags: regex, cryptography, modulo

I am wondering if it is possible to valide a code39 integer via regex. Currently I do this via a method, but in one case it is not possible to call the method, regex however is possible.

This are more or less the rules:

- integer with {7,8} // eaasy
- modulo operation // not sure if possible with regex
- last integer validate against result from modulo operation

Is this even possible with regex?

Comment: Your analysis is exactly right. Checking for integers is easy, the mathematical operations are impossible with pure regex.

Comment: @Wolph modulo operation is possible with regex because we can construct a DFA for **residue modulo m** which implies that we can write the regular expression for it too. Although it is tricky and requires basic TOC knowledge. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/CAtw91/1) for **residue modulo 3==0**

Comment: @Mandy8055 So you believe a calculation on modulo11 is possible as needed for code39? https://www.activebarcode.de/codes/checkdigit/modulo11.html

Comment: Yes it is possible but it is somewhat difficult and tricky. I can instantly show you how you can create a DFA for the same. It's a mod machine with 11 states. The problem is then you need to convert it to regular expression and write the same.

Comment: If we talk about expressive powers; then DFA, NFA and regular expression share equal power for a regular language; but then when it comes about complexity; writing the regular expression is most complex as compared to all three. But it is not impossible

Comment: @Mandy8055 I should have phrased it as practically impossible. The state diagram for the `x%3=0` is already horrible, for `(x[:-1]%11)=x[-1]` will be absolutely horrendous
https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ggg0kdwMUA8Cx8iZ

Comment: @Wolph; I agree that it is practically possible but somewhat horrible. Although; I think that if we **represent the number in binary** then; it will not be that much horrible because then sigma={0, 1} and it will boil down to a comparatively smaller regex.